# Copy only newer files from one server to another server

Tags: deployment, msbuild, windows-installer, psexec

I have a Build server and i would like to copy the newest deployment file from that location to another location on remote server using MSBuild but i am stuck on doing this as well as confused.

So in my build output directory i have a files such as this:
Installer - 2.5.1403.1201.msi
Installer - 2.5.1405.0701.msi

Now i want to copy the newest file Installer - 2.5.1405.0701.msi to remote server called ServerB.

I read that using PSExec shouldn't be used for copy files from build server to another server. Is there a reason why?

Currently i have the following code but i only got it to work locally on my machine:

```
 <ItemGroup>
   <File Include="C:\\LocalCopy\\Installer - 2.5.1403.1201.msi" />
</ItemGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
  <DestinationFolder>C:\\Dump</DestinationFolder>
</PropertyGroup>
 <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
 <Target Name="AfterBuild" Inputs="@(File)" Outputs="@(File -> '$(DestinationFolder)\% (RelativeDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(File)" DestinationFolder="$(DestinationFolder)" />
 </Target>
```

Can someone provide me with advice how i could go about doing this?

Thanks & Regards,

Comment: Are you getting a specific error message when you try to copy the file to the remote server? If I had to guess, I would say you are running into either a permissions or path issue between the account running MSBuild and the remote server folder.  Your server path should looks something like \\ServerB\<shared folder name>\

Comment: Well i need assistance in regards to how to go about copying the latest file from one server to another server.

Comment: I have the following code which pulls in two msi's but i want to copy the latest one.

I can see that there is Condition attribute on the Item of the ItemGroup.

Currently my code looks like this:
    <ItemGroup>
       <TheMSI Include="\\BuildServer\BuildOutput\Product\DEV- Stream\**\Installers\Customer\Installer.msi"/>
    </ItemGroup>

Any advice?

Thanks,